# Under VS2019, CRT call the function main() with 3 auguments, why doesn't the Complier report error "incorrect number of parameters"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, crt

In the file exe_common.inl, crt call main function like this:

```
    static int __cdecl invoke_main()
    {
        return main(__argc, __argv, _get_initial_narrow_environment());
    }
```

However, if I call main in my program with three auguments, C2660 error will occur.

just like:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int index{ 10 };
int argv{ 1 };
char** argc{ NULL };
char* env{ NULL };


int main(/*int argc, char** argv, char* env*/)
{
    cout << "index=" << index << endl;
    if (index != 0)
    {
        index--;
        main(argc, argv, env);
    }
}
```

I am so curious about the startup code, so thank you for you answer.

Comment: Internal library/compiler supporting code is allowed to do things that are forbidden to mere mortals.

Comment: In C++ it's forbidden to call [`main`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) yourself. By the way, that reference link also explains about the third argument.

Comment: Oh and also you have declared that the `main` function takes *no* arguments (in essence ignoring any arguments passed from *other* [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). This, by the way, is also a special case for the `main` function, other normal functions must have matching declarations in different translation units), which means you can't call it with arguments. It's like declaring the function `void foo();` and then attempting to call `foo` passing arguments.